# Create a date time with month and day only, no year

Tags: c#, datetime

I am creating a timer job in VS for sharepoint, and I want to create a Date object that only has a month and day. The reason for this is because I want this job to run annually on the specific date.

If it's not possible with a date object, then how would you go about doing this?

Here's what I've got:

```
DateTime value = new DateTime(2010, 1, 18);
```

Comment: Dates have years. End of story. If you want only month and date, create your own type of object to hold it.

Comment: Who will use this datetime object?

Comment: true true, I guess my question is then.. How would you be able to have a recurring date without having multiple object/events

Comment: @novicePrgrmr : what do you mean by `recurring date without....`?

Comment: @sll I mean every year at the specified month and day..

Comment: what instrumental are you using to run a job periodically or this is sharepoint internally does and you just providing a DateTime object?

Comment: Its a novice question but still a good one so +1 from me - but why the SharePoint tag? Really the Q has nothing at all to do with SharePoint (the fact that you are doing a timer job for SP is irrelevant to the Q) - same with Visual-Studio-2010. Would you put "keyboard" in as a tag?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Well, you can create your own type - but a `DateTime` *always* has a full date and time. You can't even have "just a date" using `DateTime` - the closest you can come is to have a `DateTime` at midnight.

You could always *ignore* the year though - or take the current year:

```
// Consider whether you want DateTime.UtcNow.Year instead
DateTime value = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, day);
```

To create your own type, you could always just embed a `DateTime` within a struct, and proxy on calls like `AddDays` etc:

```
public struct MonthDay : IEquatable<MonthDay>
{
    private readonly DateTime dateTime;

    public MonthDay(int month, int day)
    {
        dateTime = new DateTime(2000, month, day);
    }

    public MonthDay AddDays(int days)
    {
        DateTime added = dateTime.AddDays(days);
        return new MonthDay(added.Month, added.Day);
    }

    // TODO: Implement interfaces, equality etc
}
```

Note that the year you choose affects the behaviour of the type - should Feb 29th be a valid month/day value or not? It depends on the year...

Personally I don't think I *would* create a type for this - instead I'd have a method to return "the next time the program should be run".

Comment: @Shimmy: There's no month/day type in Noda Time, no - nor a year/month type as you might want for a credit card.

Comment: tx for your response. There is in the Java NodaTime, am I wrong?

Comment: @Shimmy: You mean in Joda Time? Yes. I haven't decided yet whether it's a sufficiently important idea to include in Noda Time - I'm trying to keep that lean.

Comment: @JonSkeet I've needed this type more than once, and keep looking it up each time. Some examples are for birthdays, where you don't want to focus on the year of birth, or for yearly recurring date intervals, where the dates are always the same.

Comment: @MikkelR.Lund: Since writing this answer (nearly 6 years ago) and the comment (2 years ago) Noda Time now *does* have `AnnualDate`.

Comment: @JonSkeet : if we have month as string like Jan, Feb, March etc. then in that case do we have anything built-in to get corresponding integer value for month. Or we need to write another method which will return corresponding integer value for month. and then we can pass it to new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, month, day);

Comment: @Ash18: You could use `DateTimeFormatInfo.MonthNames` and `DateTimeFormatInfo.AbbreviatedMonthNames`. I'm not sure that this is really related to the question you've added the comment to though - it would be better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing like a `DateTime` without a year!

From what I gather your design is a bit strange:

I would recommend storing a "start" (`DateTime` including year for the FIRST occurence) and a value which designates how to calculate the next event... this could be for example a `TimeSpan` or some custom structure esp. since "every year" can mean that the event occurs on a specific date and would not automatically be the same as saysing that it occurs in +365 days.

After the event occurs you calculate the next and store that etc.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a timer with the next date?

In your timer callback you create the timer for the following year? DateTime has always a year value. What you want to express is a recurring time specification. This is another type which you would need to create. 
DateTime is always represents a specific date and time but not a recurring date.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway you need 'Year'.

In some engineering fields, you have fixed day and month and year can be variable. But that day and month are important for beginning calculation without considering which year you are. Your user, for example, only should select a day and a month and providing year is up to you.

You can create a custom combobox using this: [Customizable ComboBox Drop-Down](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25471/Customizable-ComboBox-Drop-Down).

1- In VS create a user control.

2- See the code in the link above for impelemnting that control.

3- Create another user control and place in it 31 button or label and above them place a label to show months.

4- Place the control in step 3 in your custom combobox.

5- Place the control in setp 4 in step 1.

You now have a control with only days and months. You can use any year that you have in your database or ....