# How to display/show only date value in datetimepicker

Tags: datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

How to display/show only date value in bootstrap datetimepicker when binding data.
I have set the date format as "DD/MM/YYYY"

```
  @Html.TextBox("BirthDate", Model.BirthDate, new { @class = "form-control", @data_date_format = "DD/MM/YYYY" })
```

and also decorated the viewmodel property with datatype date.

```
      [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }
```

But when the date is binded the text box control shows the time(12:00:00 am) component as well along with date.

19/11/1945 12:00:00 a.m.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this thread. this has nothing to do with bootstrap datetimepicker.
it is with the datetime obj.
[[DateTime - How to create a date time with month and day only. (No year)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7958879/datetime-how-to-create-a-date-time-with-month-and-day-only-no-year][1])

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately that didnt work. Still the control is showing the time component as well.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing the @HTML.TextBox() to @HTML.TextBoxFor() and adding the display format
as below:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BirthDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", new { @class = "form-control", @data_date_format = "DD/MM/YYYY" })
```